# Scala change for loop mutable aggregation to immutable

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability

If I have this simple loop which is imperative style

```
val num = 100
var result = 0.0
for (i <- 0 until num) {
    result += 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1)
}
```

How would I change it to immutable and functional?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself before asking here? Paste a code snippet of your attempts before asking for the answer. I'll give you a hint, you're looking for a `fold`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an *initial value*, you iterate over a *collection* of values and apply an *operation* to each item to eventually return one *single* value.

This looks a lot like something that could be turned into a **fold**.

Comment: Might be worth providing the code that does the folding, in case he's never seen a fold before: `(0 until num).foldLeft(0.0) { (result, i) => result + 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1) }`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, with a parallel collection,

```
(1 to 100).par.map { i => 4.0 * (1 - (i % 2) * 2) / (2 * i + 1) }.sum
```